# How to vendor a modified version of active_support such that it is used in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I would like to modify the `activesupport` gem and then place it in `vendor`, such that my Rails app uses the modified version instead of the one that ships with Rails by default.

Example of my modification:

**lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:**

```
  def require(file)
    puts "--- file: #{file.inspect}"
    result = false
    load_dependency(file) { result = super }
    result
  end
```

**Question 1:** How do I place a single gem (e.g. `activesupport`) inside vendor?

**Question 2:** How do I get Rails to use that "vendorized" gem instead of the default?

Comment: For First question just do `gem unpack gem_name --target vendor/gems`

Comment: `gem unpack activesupport  --target vendor/gems`

Answer (score 0):

First Answer Do it to place a gem in vendor

```
gem unpack activesupport --target vendor/gems
```

Second Use the vendor gem instead default
in`Gemfile`

```
 gem 'activesupport', :path => "vendor/gems/activesupport-VERSION"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it matter where in `Gemfile` I add this line, like before or after `gem 'rails'`, or not?

Comment: Note that trying to bundle with `path: 'vendor/gems/activesupport'` led to the error `The path .../vendor/gems/activesupport does not exist.` I changed it to `path: 'vendor/gems/activesupport-4.0.5'` (the true relative location), and then running `bundle` worked.