# cannot load gems in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

- My app works.
- I was able to run tests before, and now for some reason I can't.
- What happened between now and then is that I vendorized `activesupport` (but I have since undone those changes, and in fact I am in a totally separate/unrelated branch).
- Two commands I ran during my work on `activesupport` that I am unfamiliar with are `bundle --deployment` and `bundle --no-deployment`. Again, I *believe* I undid everything related to those changes (**at least as far as `git status` is concerned** - I always run `git status`, and am aware of all codebase changes).

I am aware that other people have had similar, but not this exact problem: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=require+cannot+load+such+file+LoadError

I was playing around with vendorizing `activesupport` following this:
[How to vendor a modified version of active_support such that it is used in my Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603171/how-to-vendor-a-modified-version-of-active-support-such-that-it-is-used-in-my-ra)

And I had trouble when I tried pushing the vendorized `activesupport` branch to `staging`:
[Where is 'elsewhere' in "run `bundle install` elsewhere"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612444/where-is-elsewhere-in-run-bundle-install-elsewhere)

Anyway, the point is that **my app works** (i.e. all the gems are obviously installed, `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are intact), **yet I cannot run tests**:

```
/Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/rails (LoadError)
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
  from /Volumes/MyHD/Users/bsimpson/Dev/books/books/test/test_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  from test/controllers/photos_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
  from test/controllers/photos_controller_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

If I comment out line `10` of `test/test_helper.rb`, it just complains about the next `require` line.

```
dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/rails/capybara (LoadError)
...
test/test_helper.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
```

And when I comment out line `14`, it complains about the next `require` line, and so on...

So it seems that in the `test` environment, the gems aren't seen. Thoughts?

**.bundle/config**

```
---
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
```

Comment: Can you include the contents of your `.bundle/config` file?

Comment: Thanks. I have added it to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration `BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test` tells Bundler not to load gems from the `development` and `test` groups. Since this is your only configuration setting, you can safely delete the `.bundle/config` file and things should go back to working for you.

Alternatively, you could leave the file and only delete that line.

Is it possible that when you ran `bundle --deployment`, you actually ran `bundle --deployment --without development test`? These options are commonly used together, and options passed to `bundle install` (or `bundle` without a sub-command, which defaults to `install`) are remembered in the `bundle/.config` file. These options are "sticky" until they are explicitly removed, so if you use the `--without` flag once, you'll need to edit the file to get those groups back.

Also note that `.bundle/config` is usually excluded from git, so checking `git status` won't tell you if it changed. These settings are often machine-dependent, so it's a good idea to keep it excluded from git.

Comment: **Thank you SO MUCH!** I will be awarding you a bounty in 23 hours.

Comment: By the way, I checked my command logs, and it turns out I also ran `bundle install --without development test` -- but not `bundle --deployment --without development test` (i.e. not including `--deployment`). Anyway, how did you learn about these details of `bundle`?

Comment: OK yeah `--deployment` and `--without` are independent, but commonly used together. I work on Bundler in my spare time, but the docs are pretty thorough http://bundler.io/

Comment: Glad to hear that you're up and running again :-)