# cannot run tests on my computer, but coworkers can on theirs (identical codebase/branch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bundler

I have been unable to run tests on my computer, but when I push the branch to GitHub, and they pull it in, they are able to run them.

Clearly this means that our codebases are identical, including `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.

My app works in `development`, so my gems are obviously present.

What could be different in the `test` environment that prevents the tests from running?

The only thing I can think of is that there is something outside the codebase responsible for this. Perhaps something under `~/.gem/` or `~/.rvm/` -- but I don't know where to look for clues. Thoughts?

**Error from test attempt:**

```
/Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/rails (LoadError)
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/bsimpson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@books/gems/activesupport-4.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
  from /Volumes/MyHD/Users/bsimpson/Dev/books/books/test/test_helper.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  from test/controllers/photos_controller_test.rb:1:in `require'
  from test/controllers/photos_controller_test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

**gem list --local | grep minitest**

```
minitest (4.7.5, 4.3.2)
minitest-capybara (0.5.0)
minitest-metadata (0.5.0)
minitest-rails (0.9.2)
minitest-rails-capybara (0.10.0)
minitest-test (1.1.0)
```

Comment: How are your gems activated? Bundler? Rubygems? Also, what exactly do you mean by 'unable to run'?

Comment: What errors do you get trying to run the tests?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "activated"? I use Bundler, and Bundler downloads the gems from RubyGems. I have updated my question regarding what exactly happens when I try to run tests on the photos controller.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot load gems in test environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632655/cannot-load-gems-in-test-environment)

Comment: What's in your test_helper.rb file? It looks like you may have a custom version of this that isn't checked into the repo?

Comment: Nothing has changed in `test_helper.rb` since the time I could run tests. The only thing that happened in-between is that I ran two commands that I am unfamiliar with during my work on `activesupport`: `bundle --deployment` and `bundle --no-deployment`. I believe I undid everything related to those changes (at least as far as `git status` is concerned - I always run `git status`, and I am aware of all codebase changes) - this is the reason I believe the problem is *outside* my *git tracked* codebase.

Comment: @TimMoore - Yes, this is a duplicate. Just worded differently. What should I do? Delete this question? You are welcome to put an answer with a link to yours on the other question. This question came second, out of extreme frustration.

Comment: You can delete it if you like, but it doesn't hurt to leave it. Usually, moderators close duplicate questions eventually. Here's some info on duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: @TimMoore - Thank you. I will leave it, because perhaps different phrasing can lead someone to the other question/answer, and the moderators are welcome to close it. Actually, I just voted to close it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your application works in development doesn't mean that all gems are present. Testing is done not in the development environment but in the test environment.

Try running:

```
bundle install
```

Perhaps some gems were not installed correctly due to missing source dependencies. Try to see if bundle install returns any errors.

### Part 2

I've noticed that you use active_support 4.0.5. I've tried to find if upgrading minitest gem will solve the problem. I am not sure if this will work as different sites give minimal version of minitest for your version of active support. Does running:

```
gem install minitest --version '=5.1'
```

and restarting everything solve the problem?

Can we see your Gemfile?

### Part 3

Also worth trying: In your terminal go to your Rails application directory and run this:

```
rm ./Gemfile.lock 

bundle install
```

That might update your gems.

Comment: Thanks. I have already tried `bundle install` - no errors, no changes. Any other ideas?

Comment: try running: "gem list --local | grep minitest" and show me the output

Comment: By chance I noticed that you edited your answer with additional parts. FYI, SO does not notify me when you make edits to your answer, so you need to write a comment to get my attention. My problem is not an issue of what is in `Gemfile`, or the installed version of `minitest`, as I was able to run my tests perfectly fine until I did something. This something is that I ran `bundle --deployment` and `bundle --no-deployment`, but I undid any changes as far as `git status` is concerned - this is why I believe the problem is *outside* my *git tracked* codebase. I also tried your part 3 to no avail.

Comment: FYI, the question was answered in [*cannot load gems in test environment*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25777800/664833) -- but I also want to thank you for your time and effort in trying to help me. (bow)